# For wave functions $y(x, t)$, how the second order partial differentiation works as second order absolute differentiation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, free-body-diagram, string

Ref: http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/wave_equation_speed.htm

---

[image: Small section of wave]

As far as we've defined wave as the disturbance caused due to Force obeying Hooke's Law. So, the derivation was started with that, in which some steps look absurd to me!

We start by $$\sum y = T(\sin \theta_2 - \sin \theta_1) = \sigma \,dx\, a$$
For acceleration $a$. $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are small enough to be approximated as $\sin \theta_1 = \tan \theta_1$ and same for $\theta_2$. Also, $\sigma$ being linear mass density.

$$T(\tan \theta_2 - \tan \theta_1)= \sigma \, dx \dfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = \dfrac{T}{\sigma} \dfrac{ \left( \dfrac{\partial y(x+ dx)}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x} \right)}{dx}= \dfrac T \sigma \dfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}\tag{*}  \\ \Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = v^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}$$

Here the $(*)$ was giving me issues. We know that tangent at a given point is given by the absolute derivative of a curve at that point, but how $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$? For wave equations $y$, the $y$(s) are the function of both time and $x$ axis, so how can partial derivative make sense for absolute derivative for equations having 2 variables?

Also, the $\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = a$ for functions of 2 variables like $y$ shouldn't be working as absolute derivative!

Comment: Should the first line open $\sum F_y = \dots$? Also, as an aside, you should *say* that $\sigma$ is the linear mass density so that $\mathrm{d}m = \sigma\,\mathrm{d}x$ (assuming that the slope is quite small as usual in the simply version of this derivation). I can guess that because I've seen this kind of thing before, but it is good technical writing style to specify such matters.

Comment: @dmckee oh okay :)

Comment: I think it's just notation issues what you're having. You have to remember that the RHS of $(*)$ applies for a constant $x$ value, while the LHS has the (spatial) tangent at two distinct $x$'s but all is calculated at the same $t$. Hence you should use partials to be clear what is being held constant.

Comment: @ErickShock Aha!!! Gotcha! Thanks :)